# Sorl Suggester issue

Tags: solr

I'm using solr Suggester lookupImpl as AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory , it's working fine the only issue i am not able to resolve is the fact I want exact search keyword display on top.

.i.e if I1`q search "Leather bags" then that particular keywords should display on top but it is showing "mens leather", "ladies leather bags" after that it is showing "Leather bags".

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">mySuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str> 
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">search_keyword</str>

<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
</lst>     
</searchComponent>

please help
```

Comment: you need to change the fieldtype for your field...currently its text_general...use keywordTokenizer for it if you are looking for exact matches

Comment: hi, thanks for your valuable reply. i have used "keywordTokenizer" but it is searching record form prefix it is not searching in middle of the keyword. if i search "leather bags" and there is a record "ladies leather bags" then it's not displaying in result.

Comment: Try by adding *leather bags...

Comment: Could you please share the fieldType defined for your field search_keyword

Comment: try with <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>..and t

Comment: Hi  Abhijit Bashetti , it's working fine now after using KeywordTokenizerFactory
thanks

Comment: I will add it as answer, Please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by changing the field type for your field `suggestAnalyzerFieldType`.
Currently the field suggestAnalyzerFieldType has text_general as the field type for your field.
Use `keywordTokenizer` for your field if you are looking for exact matches. As it does not create tokens of the text.

The `keywordTokenizer` is : This tokenizer treats the entire text field as a single token.

[image: KeywordTokenizer Image]